# Should I use subjunctive in a sentence that is the consequence of another sentence that uses the subjunctive?

Tags: subjonctif

For example, if I say "Supposons qu'il y ait [qch], cela signifie que ...", where "cela" refers to the "[qch]", then should I use the subjunctive of "signifier"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the conditional, not the subjunctive.

- Supposons qu'il y ait des erreurs, cela pourrait/<s>puisse</s> avoir de graves conséquences.

You can also use the indicative in the present.

- Supposons qu'il y ait des erreurs, cela peut avoir de graves conséquences.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't use the subjunctive for *signifie*.

"Cela signifie..." is a main clause. You could change the comma in your sentence for a full stop:

> Supposons *(main clause 1)* qu'il y ait [qch] (*subordinate clause*). Cela signifie (*main clause 2*) que [...]

Most of the time, subjunctive occurs in a subordinate clause, not a main clause. You could however use conditional (*cela signifierait que*) to mark hypothesis.